# how to save another image in android?

Tags: android, image, android-studio, uiimageview

```
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View b) {
            if ( ( d1.getText().toString().trim().equals("") ) && d2.getText().toString().trim().equals("")
                    && d3.getText().toString().trim().equals("") && d4.getText().toString().trim().equals("") && d5.getText().toString().trim().equals("")
                    && d6.getText().toString().trim().equals("") )
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Generate before Save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Qr Image Has Been Save in /DCIM/Camera ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //attempt to save the image

                b = findViewById(R.id.image);
                b.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap bitmap = b.getDrawingCache();
                File file = new File("/DCIM/Camera/");
                File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File cachePath = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/image.jpeg");
                try {
                cachePath.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(cachePath);

                 bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);
                    ostream.flush();
                    ostream.close();


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    });


    }





}
```

is there anyway to save another another image from my image view instead of overwrite the previous image? by the way this code worked but i cant save another image with another name. can someone help me?

Comment: please provide the whole activity's code

Comment: Use Path.GetTempFileName()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving same name to all the image `File cachePath = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/image.jpeg");`, Just change it or append timestamp at the end.

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
File cachePath = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/image" + timeStamp + ".jpeg");
```

Comment: thank you sir your code really worked, but if possible, is there anyway to change the time stamp to incremental number like IMG1, IMG2, IMG3?

Comment: create a static counter in baseclass, or store counter in sharedpreferences and increase it whenever you add new images\

Comment: i would be grateful if you can provide me the code as i am new to android developer,  thank you very much sir.

Comment: I would love to share code with you, but as you are fresher i suggest you to search it by own, you will learn something :)

Answer (score 0):

you **should change**

```
File cachePath = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/image.jpeg");
```

possible **work around**

**create a new alert dialog with custom editText, save the name of the image in the editText, set it to String value**

```
String renmae=editText.getText().toString();
File cachePath = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/" + renmae+ ".jpeg");
```

or **else** save the name using **timestamp**

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
File cachePath = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/image" + timeStamp + ".jpeg");
```

Comment: thank you sir your code really worked, but if possible, is there anyway to change the time stamp to incremental number like IMG1, IMG2, IMG3?

Comment: yes, use a static variable of data type int and add it to the File cache

Static int i =1;

`File cachePath = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/" + renmae+ ""+i+".jpeg");`

**after saving ** change i = i++; // for incrementing the i to 2

@HarrisFreds

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
String imageName="image-"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpeg";

File cachePath = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/"+imageName);
```

All times ,the imagename is different.

Comment: thank you sir your code really worked, but if possible, is there anyway to change the time stamp to incremental number like IMG1, IMG2, IMG3?

Comment: you can add one counter variable.and its increment by 1.so u solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View b) {
            if ( ( d1.getText().toString().trim().equals("") ) && d2.getText().toString().trim().equals("")
                    && d3.getText().toString().trim().equals("") && d4.getText().toString().trim().equals("") && d5.getText().toString().trim().equals("")
                    && d6.getText().toString().trim().equals("") )
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Generate before Save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Qr Image Has Been Save in /DCIM/Camera ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //attempt to save the image

                b = findViewById(R.id.image);
                b.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap bitmap = b.getDrawingCache();
                File file = new File("/DCIM/Camera/");
                File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File cachePath = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/image_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpeg");
                try {
                cachePath.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(cachePath);

                 bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);
                    ostream.flush();
                    ostream.close();
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),cachePath.getAbsolutePath(),cachePath.getName(),cachePath.getName());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    });

    }
```

Comment: thank you sir your code really worked, but if possible, is there anyway to change the time stamp to incremental number like IMG1, IMG2, IMG3?

Comment: @HarrisFreds You can use one int count instead of System.currentTimeMillis(). 
int Count = 1 ;
"/DCIM/Camera/image_"+Count+".jpeg");
......

Count++;